# Qt Parent Child Relationships

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm running a test to understand parent/child relationships in Qt and I have a question about how I can view these relationships in the Qt Creator Debugger.

When I start my demo application, here is what the debugger shows:

[image: Application Starts]

Because I call Qt's dumpObjectTree() before I add any widgets, the tree is empty, except for the MainWindow's layout.  That's what I expected.

When I close the application, and the ~MainWindow destructor is called, I call dumpObjectTree() again, but this time, all of the widgets that I created show in the tree.  If I called dumpObjectTree() after the window was destroyed, shouldn't the tree be empty again?

[image]

Am I not destroying the child widgets correctly, or do I misunderstand the information displayed by the dumpObjecTree() function?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{

    qDebug() << "WINDOW INITIALIZED-------------";
    dumpObjectTree();
    this->buildLayout();

}

void MainWindow::buildLayout() {

    QWidget *window = new QWidget(this);
    this->setObjectName("Main Window");

    layout = new QVBoxLayout();

    QSplitter *split = new QSplitter();
    split->setObjectName("Horizontal Split");
    split->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    QTextEdit *editor1 = new QTextEdit();
    editor1->setObjectName("Editor 1");
    QTextEdit *editor2 = new QTextEdit();
    editor2->setObjectName("Editor 2");
    split->addWidget(editor1);
    split->addWidget(editor2);

    QSplitter *split2 = new QSplitter();
    split2->setObjectName("Vertical Split");
    split2->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
    QTextEdit *editor3 = new QTextEdit();
    editor3->setObjectName("Editor 3");
    split2->addWidget(split);
    split2->addWidget(editor3);

    QToolBar *mainToolbar = new QToolBar();
    mainToolbar->setObjectName("Main Toolbar");
    mainToolbar->addAction("Main Button 1");
    mainToolbar->addSeparator();
    mainToolbar->addAction("Main Button 2");
    mainToolbar->setMovable(true);

    layout->addWidget(mainToolbar);
    layout->addWidget(split2);

    QToolBar *toolbar = new QToolBar(this);
    toolbar->setObjectName("Mini Toolbar");
    toolbar->addAction("Button 1");
    toolbar->addSeparator();
    toolbar->addAction("Button 2");
    toolbar->setMovable(true);

    QMenuBar *menu = new QMenuBar(this);
    menu->setObjectName("Menu Bar");
    menu->addAction("Menu 1");
    menu->addAction("Menu 2");
    menu->addAction("Menu 3");

    window->setLayout(layout);

    MainWindow::addToolBar(toolbar);
    MainWindow::setMenuBar(menu);
    MainWindow::setCentralWidget(window);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

    delete layout;
    qDebug() << "DESTROYED " << this->metaObject()->className();
    qDebug() << "OBJECT TREE-------------";
    dumpObjectTree();
    qDebug() << "OBJECT INFO-------------";
    dumpObjectInfo();

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is that when your `MainWindow` destructor is called, the window is only part of the way through being destroyed.

In particular, the child widgets do not get deleted through the parent-child mechanism until the `QObject` destructor is called, which occurs after that, so at the point you call dumpObjectTree() all the children still exist.

Comment: Thanks!  If I pass the parent to the constructor of a widget, such as new QComboBox(this), referring to the MainWindow, is it best to pass (this) or the actual parent?  For example, if I created a widget named *myWidget and I added a new QComboBox to it, should I initialize it as new ComboBox(this) or new ComboBox(myWidgt)?

Comment: The QComboBox's parent will be changed once it's added to a layout, so it doesn't really matter which parent you pass in the constructor unless there's the possibility of an exception being thrown between the time it's constructed and the time it's added.